# UIImage.size different from pixel resolution?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm resizing an *UIImage*, after the resizing if I print the size:

```
print(myImage.size)
```

I get the output:

> (295.5, 350.0)

After saving the image I check the resolution and I get:
555 × 700 pixels

Isn't the *UIImage.size* the resolution of the image?

Comment: The [`size` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size) describes the connection between logical size and pixel dimension: "This value reflects the logical size of the image .... Multiply the size values by the value in the scale property to get the pixel dimensions of the image."

Comment: What do you mean? @MartinR

Comment: So it depends on the *scale*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get pixel resolution of your image you could use next snippet:

```
let image: UIImage = ...
let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * image.scale, height: image.size.height * image.scale)
```

It takes into account image's scale value.